# How to send a message or alert to a mobile phone if it is connected to wifi?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, wifi, alert

Is there a method to send a message or alert to an **unknown mobile** which is connected to a free **wifi(open LAN)** network. I know this can be done using mobile application. But I'm expecting to do it with thought installing any app. Message have to be send only through the LAN wifi. Any idea please? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Being able to push unsolicited messages to a device would pose a security risk. Mobile devices do not have such a messaging protocol that would allow for such messages.

You may want to look into a "captive portal" which will redirect all network traffic to a specified page, perhaps a webpage with your intended message. A captive portal could be configured with a white-list to get close to what you are looking for.

Some phones will pop-up this captive portal upon connection (I know iphones default to doing this). Others may not see the message until they attempt to open a browser.

This solution does require such feature to be either enabled on your router (Few have this option, typically ones with a 'guest wifi') or an advanced configuration including a webserver and some sort of authentication.